# Force reboot between installs with Visual Studio Setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

I'm creating a project C# with Visual Studio. I use a Setup project to generate an installer. This installer check if SQL Server is present, if not the installation is perform (with .NET framework).

But I have a problem. When the installer have to install SQL server, it install .NET framework before. After that the SQL Server's installation failed. If I reboot and re-install, the installation is OK.

I use a SDK package (like this https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/how-about-a-bootstrapper-package-for-sqlserver-express-2008-r2/) for SQL server and .NET framework. I modified the package.xml in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX35SP1 with `<Command PackageFile="dotNetFx35setup.exe" Arguments=" /lang:fra /passive /forcerestart">`

But there is no restart after installation for .NET 3.5.

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue is probably that the documentation for installing the 3.5 framework doesn't include "forcerestart":

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160716.aspx

so it's probably being ignored.

It doesn't appear that NET 3.5 is supported any more. Is it possible that later versions don't have this issue?